# Hide div on scroll , show div on stop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to show the top div on stop scroll and hide it when a user scrolls. I have the code working in the reverse, can someone work out how to reverse it so that the div shows on stop scroll and hides when the user scrolls.

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  $('top').stop(true, true).show().fadeOut('fast');
});
```

```css
top {
  position: fixed;
  background: #000;
  color: #eee;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<top>Show me on scroll</top>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</p>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
 $(window).scroll(function() {
      $('top').stop(true, true).hide().fadeIn('fast');
    });
```

and css:

```
top {
  position: fixed;
  background: #000;
  color: #eee;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  display: block;
}
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o9p2mk4q/1/)

Comment: 'div shows on stop scroll and hides when the user scrolls.' Check fiddle

Comment: Great Solution, Thank you

Comment: Try scroll it slowly. Not good experience. Now check my solution. I really think that encompassing debounce function is better approach.

Answer (score 0):

Use debounce function from underscore, or write own debounce function. Try this live demo. Is simple and IMO it provides best user experience:

```js
var $hideMe = $('#imHiddenDuringScroll')

var hideIt = _ => {
  $hideMe.fadeOut('fast')
  showItLazy()
}
var showItLazy = _.debounce(_ => {
  $hideMe.fadeIn('fast')
}, 350)

$(window).scroll(hideIt)
```

```css
#imHiddenDuringScroll {
  position: fixed;
  background: #000;
  color: #eee;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  padding: 10px;
}
#longScrollableText {
  width: 270px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/jquery@3.2.1/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/underscore@1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>

<div id="imHiddenDuringScroll">I am hidden during scroll</div>
<div id="longScrollableText">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod    incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis ostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. uis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit met, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in rehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia        deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur dipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim eniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo onsequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, unt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
```